# Function as service in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am storing a string in database that I want to access from various places in my application. I figure out that the best solution will be create a function that is taking that string from database and register it as a service.

Function:

```
public function shopUrlAction()
{ 
  return new Response($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Settings')->find(1)->getName());
}
```

service.yml

```
services:
  app.default_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController
```

output in other controller:

```
$return['base_url'] = $this->forward('app.default_controller:shopUrlAction');
```

Unfortunately I am constantly getting

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   "You have requested a non-existent service "app.default_controller"."
>   at /app/bootstrap.php.cache line
>   2099  Context:
>   {"exception":"Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException)"}

I've cleared cache.

Comment: Why are you using `$this->forward();`? You should do `$this->get('app.default_controller')->shopUrlAction();` instead.

Comment: Sorry that was me trying weird solutions. Using $this->get still outputing You have requested a non-existent service "app.default_controller"

Comment: is your file service.yml is well registered in your DependencyInjection extension file ?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `AppBundle` is in the root of the `src` directory?

Comment: Why don't you create a service class that both/any of your controllers can use?

Comment: I think the problem is with proper registering of services.yml, as Freelancer pointed out. When I put code from services.yml to config.yml, the service is recognised in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your question you have `service.yml` instead of `services.yml` (in plural form).

You should include your `service.yml` in main `config.yml` in `imports` section or use standard path to it (`AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`)